# Options for storing Session state with SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, wss

I have written a user control for our SharePoint site that builds an HTML menu - this has been injected into the master page and as such ends up rendering on all pages that use it. There are some pretty computationally expensive calls made while generating this HTML and caching is the logical choice for keeping the page loads snappy. The HttpRuntime Cache has worked perfectly for this so far.

Now we are embarking down version 1.1 of this user control and a new requirement has crept in to allow per-user customization of the menu. Not a problem, except that I can no longer blindly use the HttpRuntime Cache object - or at least, not use it without prefacing the user id and making it user specific someway.

Ideally I would like to be able to use the ASP.NET Session collection to store the user specific code. I certainly don't need it hanging around in the cache if the user isn't active and further, this really is kind of session specific data. I have looked at several options including it in the ViewState or enabling Session management (by default it is disabled for [a good reason](http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=69)). But I am really not all that happy with either of them.

So my question is: How should I go about caching output like this on a per user basis? Right now, my best bet seems to be include their user id in the Cache key, and give it a sliding expiration.

Comment: I think you may be taking the performance impact of enabling session state too seriously.  Instead of relying on one opinion which paints this "end of days" view on using Sessions, you should performance test it for yourself to measure the impact on your particular site.  In this linked example they are saying "Why enable sessions on a site where you only need it 3 places if there's 997 that don't need it?".  Well good news, unless you don't show menus on some pages you need it on every page.  Test and determine the impact yourself; it should be minimal.

Comment: @Nissan Fan: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth pointing out that I believe the 'end of days' link providing is relevant for SPS2003 not MOSS2007 - afaik MOSS integration into Asp.Net means that the mentioned issue is not a problem in MOSS.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it is closest to the comment left by Nissan Fan and states something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I use ViewState on a fairly large MOSS 2007 deployment (1000+ users) for custom webparts and pages, and I haven't noticed a detrimental effect on the deployment performance at all.

Just use it, is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wouldn't use SharePoints built in web part caching mechanism for this on a per user basis (Personal) - its exactly what its designed for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.partcacheread.aspx

Comment: I am not developing a web part - this is a user control dropped in the CONTROLTEMPLATES folder.